# 'TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function' error happening in React project has something to do with './node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, binding, material-ui, node-sass

So I've been trying to figure this for a while right now and I'm at the end of my rope here.

I'm trying to create a react application that makes simple API calls but I keep getting this error that prevents my lodable component from being rendered.

It comes out as a props.error which I log into chrome's console.log()

In the chrome's console I get:

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
at Object.hasBinary (extensions.js:404)
at module.exports (binding.js:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:14)
at Object../node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js (index.js:471)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:772)
at fn (bootstrap:141)
at Object../src/routes/app/routes/tacas/components/FeatureCallouts.js (lib sync:9)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:772)
at fn (bootstrap:141)
at Object../src/routes/app/routes/tacas/components/template.js (styles.scss?8f6b:45)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:772)
at fn (bootstrap:141)
at Object../src/routes/app/routes/tacas/index.js (index.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:772)
at fn (bootstrap:141)
```

I think it has something to do with the './node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js' file which is:

```
/*!
 * node-sass: lib/binding.js
 */

var errors = require('./errors');

/**
 * Require binding
 */
module.exports = function(ext) {
  if (!ext.hasBinary(ext.getBinaryPath())) {
    if (!ext.isSupportedEnvironment()) {
      throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
    } else {
      throw new Error(errors.missingBinary());
    }
  }

  return require(ext.getBinaryPath());
};
```

Also in the build CMD terminal, I am also getting this Warning:

```
./node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js
19:9-37 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I've looked at other questions similar to this but none seem to work for me. For instance, I don't have a webpack.config file at all.

Just in case here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "material",
  "private": true,
  "version": "4.0.0",
  "main": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "stop": "taskkill -F -IM node.exe",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prettier": "prettier --write ./src/**/**/**/*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^2.0.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.7",
    "downshift": "^2.1.1",
    "echarts": "^4.1.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.14",
    "element-resize-event": "^2.0.9",
    "font-awesome": "~4.7.0",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "~1.3.8",
    "material-ui-pickers": "1.0.0-rc.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "rc-queue-anim": "^1.6.5",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.4",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.0-next.3e165448",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "development": [
      "last 2 chrome versions",
      "last 2 firefox versions",
      "last 2 edge versions"
    ],
    "production": [
      ">0.25%",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "react-app-rewire-provide-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

Please help, I'm an intern at work and this is the first project I've gotten and I don't want to mess it up.

Comment: did you get solve this issue. Because me also having the same error. So if you find a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

VS Code auto imported `TRUE` from node-sass while I was typing thus adding `import {TRUE} from 'node-sass'` in the file, which resulted in this error.
Removing it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

VS Code auto-imported `Null` just like @SadAzzi Answer, Removing it everything worked like a charm for me.

`import { NULL } from "node-sass"`;

Answer (score 0):

Node-sass is a native C++ module and can't be run in the browser. It's possible dart-sass might, but I've never tried

Comment: I'm using a template that uses node-sass and what's called react-app-rewire:
This is what is in my package.json how run this in a test environment then?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem. For some reason, `import {TRUE} from 'node-sass` was imported (not by me). The steps I took to resolve this was to uninstall SCSS, SASS Loader, and get rid of that aforementioned import. I am not sure if this would help, but I wanted to post this because I have been researching this error for the past two days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find and remove the following line from your code, probably it's been imported by accident by your IDE. Most likely that is the problem

```
import { render } from 'node-sass';
```